# Springboot application dont get correctly the value from Spring Config Server properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config-server

I have a little issue and i really dont know why this is happening

```
@RefreshScope
@Configuration
@Getter
public class ConfigProperties {

   @Value("${receipts.Application}")
   private String application;
   @Value("${receipts.ApplicationIdMT}")
   private String applicationIdMT;
   @Value("${receipts.IdComercioMT}")
   private String idComercioMT;
   //more properties
}
```

i have this configuration class i get the values from a application.yml this file is in a git repository because my proyect use a config server to fetch the values

my application.yml in git repo looks like this:

```
receipts:
   Application: NAVERU
   ApplicationIdMT: b96f9c62-e6a
   IdComercioMT: 02500000012
   //more properties
```

when i fetch the values something weird happen, a example of my class is this:

```
   //logic and imports....
   public class ClientBase {

       @Autowired
       protected ConfigProperties configProperties;

       public void printValues(){

       String application= configProperties.getApplication();
       String applicationIdMT= configProperties.getApplicationIdMT();
       String idComercioMT= configProperties.getIdComercioMT();
       System.out.println("aplication: "+application);
       System.out.println("idMt: "+applicationIdMT);
       System.out.println("idComerceMt: "+idComercioMT);
       }
       
  }
```

And when i see the values in console:

```
     aplication: NAVERU
     idMt: b96f9c62-e6a
     idComerceMt: 352321546
```

i dont understeand why **idComerceMt** comes with that value because like i show the real value is **02500000012**

Comment: seems like something got cached somewhere and is yet to be updated. Are you running from the IDE or from a build tool?

Comment: As @RobEvans mentioned, seems like it is cached somewhere. Try changing the value at GIT for the ones what appears correct and run the test, if it shows the old value then that means you program is reading cached data. Whatever editor you are using, try restarting it or restart the application to see the refreshed value.

Comment: See if you can debug where ConfigProperties is actually picking up properties from

Comment: @RobEvans i am using my IDE in my local env, i clean the project, restart my IDE, restart the config server and the project with this issue, i can see that if i put new properties in git repo i get the correct value but when the property is alphanumeric or string, but with numbers like this 00221511...etc i get wrong values :/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the value of `IdComercioMT` is being read as a number, and being 0-prefixed, it is being parsed in **octal**.

`02500000012`<sub>*(octal)*</sub> = `352321546`<sub>*(decimal)*</sub>

Since the Configuration class wants the value as a String, you can fix it easily by quoting the value:

```yaml
receipts:
   Application: NAVERU
   ApplicationIdMT: b96f9c62-e6a
   IdComercioMT: '02500000012'
   # more properties
```

Comment: Thanks this really solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Check the values in your property file in target\BOOT-INF\classes

Comment: i dont find that folder, but i search in ".../AppData\Local\Temp\config-repo-7675019279324585074" (the last generated) and into it i see all my application.yml from git repo but local and it have the actual correct value of 02500000012, i dont know why when i execute my project that value comes wrong.